# Example of a minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containing $R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a non-empty set, and let $R$ be a relation on $A$. Define the **minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containing $R$** to be the intersection of all equivalence relations on $A$ that contain $R$.

I understood this definition, but I’m not quite sure of how it works. Can someone **provide some examples** of a set $A$, a relation $R$ on $A$ and the minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containing $R$? So I can get to know how this works. Any example is welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 1**: $A=\Bbb Z$, and $R=\{(m,m+1)\colon m\in \Bbb Z\}$, or in other words $mRn$ if and only if $n=m+1$. Then the minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containining $R$ is the universal equivalence relation $\{(m,n)\colon m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$, where every integer is related to every other integer.

**Example 2**: $A=\Bbb Z$, and $R=\{(m,m+2)\colon m\in \Bbb Z\}$, or in other words $mRn$ if and only if $n=m+2$. Then the minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containining $R$ is the equivalence relation where $m$ is related to $n$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ have the same parity.

**Example 3**: $A$ is any set and $R$ is any equivalence relation. Then the minimal equivalence relation containing $R$ is $R$ itself.

**Example 4**: $A$ is any set, and $R=\emptyset$ is the empty relation, where nothing is related to anything else. Then the minimal equivalence relation contining $R$ is the equality relation $\{(x,x)\colon x\in A\}$, where $x$ is related to $y$ if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: Suppose that we have the relation $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$. What would be the minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containing $<$? (In my thoughts there are none, but I think this is wrong)

Comment: @AirMike It's already transitive, so make it symmetric: "$a<b$ or $b<a$" ($a\lessgtr b$) and then make it reflexive: "$a\lessgtr b$ or $a=b$" ($a\lesseqgtr b$). By the [trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)#Trichotomy_on_numbers), this is a pretty extreme equivalence relation.

Comment: And that would be the minimal equivalence relation on $A$ containing $<$?

Comment: Yes. And in general, the everything-is-equivalent equivalence relation contains every relation $R$, so there will never be no such candidates.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if all you want is an example...

Let $A = \mathbb Z$ and let $R = \{(3,7), (2,7)\}$.  That *is* a relation on $\mathbb Z$ although it's a very boring and rather pointless.  $3 R 7$  and $2 R 7$ but nothing else is related to anything.

This is obviously *not* an equivalence relation.  It's not reflexive.  There is *no* $a Ra$.  It's not symmetric.  $(3,7) \in R$ but $(7,3)\ne R$.  Counterintuively it *is* transitive as there are *no* pair of $(a,b)$ *AND* $(b,c) \in R$.

Now to make it an equivalence relation we must add some $(a,b)$. But which ones and how few can we get away with.

To make it reflexive we must add every $(a,a)$ where $a \in \mathbb Z$.

To make it symmetric, because it has $(3,7)$ and $(2,7)$ we must add $(7,3)$ and $(7,2)$.

Now we have $(3,7),(7,3),(2,7),(7,2)$ and to make it transitive as we have $(3,7),(7,2)$ (and $(7,3),(3,2)$) we need $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$.

So now we have $S = \{(a,a)|a\in Z\}\cup {(2,3),(2,7),(3,2),(3,7),(7,2),(7,3)\}$.

That is

1. $S$ is an equivalence relationship on $\mathbb Z$>
2. $R = \{(3,7),(2,7)\} \subset S$
3. $S$ is the smallest equivalence on $\mathbb Z$ that contains $R$.

Comment: How do you make sure it is the smallest?

Comment: By only adding what you need and no more.  ... There is no set method for solving these.  I'm merely telling you what the definition means.

Comment: got it! Thank you for the explanation! I’m gonna follow that method and see where it takes me :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3789423 Does this agree with your suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A common example is this: you have $B\subseteq A$ and you want all the elements of $B$ to be equivalent, but all the others to be equivalent only to themselves. This is achieved through the least equivalence $R_B$ such that $a R_B b$ for all $a,b\in B$. Id est:

$$x R_B y\Leftrightarrow ((x\in B\land y\in B)\lor (x=y))$$

You should check that the predicate on the RHS actually defines an equivalence, and convince yourself that it is the least equivalence containing $B\times B$.

Comment: Is least and minimal equivalent terminology?

Comment: @AirMike In this context yes, because there aren't two minimal equivalences containing a relation $R$: a minimal such equivalence is also the least such equivalence.